# Could we get the red highlight in the timeline?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, timeline

Could we add some highlighting to the timeline to emphasise critical actions like delete/undelete. Now everything looks the same. Could we get this emphasis back for major actions, so that the stand out amongst the less important events?

[image]

In this screenshot there are only 3 actions, but when a post has more actions you have to visually scan through all to find if the post was deleted/undeleted previously.

Comment: I only remember that red highlight being on review results and that's still there. Was it really on delete votes as well?

Comment: I thought it was. If it wasn't could we still add some highlighting?

Comment: Deleted comments and answers, and flags still has a red background in the post timeline. I don't think history items (delete/close votes) ever had a red background unless they were mod-only.

Comment: As far as I know there was never any highlighting for actions such as delete/undelete or close/reopen. Those have always been things that I've had to scan through the timeline to find. If you want this to be a feature request, then I'd suggest that it be clear what you are asking for. Alternately, we could have answers making various suggestions...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on our [current roadmap](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/28/the-loop-community-public-platform-roadmap-q1-2021/), this isn't work that we will take on, as it doesn't coincide with functional areas that we plan to improve in the near future. We recognize that time and thought was put into this request, but unfortunately, we can't prioritize it at this time.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think this would make any sense.

The red background has always been used to indicate that the thing you are looking at is deleted. Handled flags have a red background because the flag is now deleted. Retracted or completed close votes have a red background because they are deleted. A history event cannot be in a deleted state, and shouldn't have a red background because that doesn't match the use case for that background.

Those events have always appeared exactly as they appear now. The current styling matches how timeline events are meant to be shown and is consistent with styles across the site. While that may mean that regular users almost never encounter a red background in the timeline, adding red backgrounds in places they don't belong would be incredibly confusing for staff and moderators that depend on the red background signifying a specific thing.